# Iterate through a SC.ManyArrray to create custom views to append to another view in SproutCore

Tags: javascript, sproutcore

I'm trying to figure out how I can retrieve a set of objects from the datastore, pass the SC.ManyArray to a controller then have a view iterate over the arrangedObjects to create custom SC.Views that I'd like to be able to append to other various views already appended to the DOM.

All I can find are examples of how to do this using the SproutCore pre built ListView/CollectionView/TableView etc. But I need these generated custom views to be appended to other views.

On another related but separate issue, when I inspect the object returned from the call to MyApp.store.find() the dataHashes property doesn't include all of my fixtures that I've included. I'm not sure if it's because I haven't created a view to call the data yet though because if I use the console I can return all the fixtures.

I'll also add that the data I'm retrieving is coming from a toMany relation from the master record. I'm retrieving the SC.ManyArray using a binding to the content of the SC.ArrayController with the path MyApp.masterModel.relationProperty.

Edit: I meant to say MyApp.masterModelController.relationProperty

Any insight would be great. I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days now and there doesn't seem to be any information found with google or the SproutCore docs.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out...

What I ended up doing is creating a `SC.CollectionView` and bound the content to the `SC.ArrayController` used to managed the data collection. When I added this collection view to the `childViews` array, it automagically fetched the fixtures related to the models toMany relation and created the custom views I created and set as the `exampleView` on the `SC.CollectionView` and the stores `dataHashes` property was updated with these objects.

On the custom view I created to display the objects I overrode the `didAppendToDocument` method, acquired the path to the container view for the views I wanted to append these to and used `appendChild` to append the created custom views.

The last thing needed was to hide the `SC.CollectionView` so I just set the `layout` property to `{top:-1000,left:-1000,width:0,height:0}`.

I'm not 100% sure this is the best way to approach this but it does work (for me at least).

I'd love to hear any other suggestions to accomplish this.

Comment: To hide a view, all you need to do is update the `isVisible` property of the view to be `false` :-)